# Does $SO(7)$ have a universal covering by $SU(6)$?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, quaternions

A question which I'm sure is inane to an expert on Lie groups, but since $SU(2)$ has a universal covering to $SO(3)$, and $SU(2)$ is isomorphic to the unit quaternions, this question might be entertained for the following reason:

The Quaternions enjoy a complexification into the Octinions in which they remain a division algebra (though fail to be associative). Although I'm sure the non-associativity of $\mathbb{O}$ kills the prospect of finding an isomorphism from its unit ball to $SU(6)$, it might be the case that the geometry extends between the two higher dimensional Lie groups, even if the algebraic structure probably doesn't.

The question first arose due to comments on [Can octonions be used to rotate 7-dimensional vectors?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2061606/can-octonions-be-used-to-rotate-7-dimensional-vectors)

Comment: Where are you getting $SU(6)$ from?

Comment: It was discussed at length in the question and linked question. No doubt it is resolved now by the answer of James Cameron.

Comment: In the linked question, it was you who brought up $SU(6)$. I am curious what made you think of the group $SU(6)$. (Actually, just now something came to me. Were you suspecting a relationship between $SO(n)$ and $SU(n-1)$ when $n$ is the dimension of imaginary elements? It was not clear to me this was the numerological basis for referencing $SU(6)$; I did not see where you were getting $SU(6)$ from at all.)

Comment: @arctic_tern You are correct, but it was not me who brought up $SO(7)$. The (albeit naive) question of whether or not there is a similar $SU(n-1) \rightarrow SO(n)$ cover for $n = 7$ as exists for $n = 3$ made sense at the time. It may help to think of me as a child playing with something he doesn't understand rather than a deep and/or professional mathematician.

Comment: Totally fine. I just wanted to understand why $SU(6)$ was being brought up at all. (Not sure why you're saying it wasn't you who brought up $SO(7)$; I was talking about $SU(6)$.)

Comment: I was saying that because my naive question about $SU(6)$ makes sense if you are already thinking about $SO(7)$ and know the of the isomorphism $Spin(3) = SU(2)$ without necessarily understanding the structure behind it. In this case, the answer was of the best sort--that helps you understand the big picture--and its popularity is well-deserved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The universal cover of $SO(n)$ is the group $Spin(n)$. For small values of $n$, there are isomorphisms between various compact simply connected Lie groups that you might not expect, corresponding to accidental isomorphisms between small Dynkin diagrams. We have the one you mentioned; $Spin(3)=SU(2)$. There is also $Spin(4)=SU(2) \times SU(2)$, and $Spin(5)=Sp(2)$, and $Spin(6)=SU(4)$.

However, we know that $Spin(7)$ isn't $SU(6)$ since $SU(6)$ is $35$ dimensional and $SO(7)$ is $21$ dimensional.

Comment: Succinct and straightforward. Excellent answer; thank you!